# Windows 10 will not shut down completely

Tags: windows-10

I recently installed windows 10 in my computer, but i got a problem :I click "Shut Down" on Start Menu. then Screen goes dark, but my machine does not power off. I have to manually press the Power off button on my machine. so any help plllllz

Comment: If it's an upgrade from older windows, I suggest a clean install. That solved several issues for me together. Then let the windows update run its course.

Comment: disable fast boot: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Wait a little longer while Windows saves some things before you manually press the Power Off. If you completely hate this follow the instructions above by by magicandre1981

Comment: Also, removing junk and defragmenting your hard drive *could* speed things up a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to downgrade Intel Management Engine Interface driver to 9.5.24.1790 (search Intel site). This helped in my case.

Good Luck! (: